# How to send packet to client with private ip?

Tags: server, udp, client, nat, packets

I make client and server in c# and i want to send packets between this 2 applications. When client send message to server everything is good, server accept it. But when server try to reply, client not receive message. I think, it is problem because i have private ip (i am not sure, but i think it is NAT - 1 ip and a lot of computers) and my server is running on my VPS.
So, how to reply to client from server?

Client Code:

```
    void SendDataToServer(string Message)
    {
        IPAddress Ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("mydomain.com").AddressList[0];
        int Port = 1234;
        IPEndPoint Server = new IPEndPoint(Ip, Port);

        byte[] MessageInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Message);
        MySocket.SendTo(MessageInBytes, Server);
    }

    void ReceiveDataFromServer(int Port) // this is running in background
    {
        UdpClient Client = new UdpClient(Port);
        IPEndPoint Server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] MessageInBytes = Client.Receive(ref Server);
                string Message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(MessageInBytes, 0, MessageInBytes.Length);
                MessageBox.Show(Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e);
        }
    }
```

Server Code:

```
    static void StartReceiveing(int Port) // this is running in background
    {
        UdpClient Server = new UdpClient(Port);
        IPEndPoint Client = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] MessageInBytes = Server.Receive(ref Client);
                string Message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(MessageInBytes, 0, MessageInBytes.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Received message: " + Message);
                Task.Run(() => ReplyToClient("some text", Client));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    static void ReplyToClient(string Message, IPEndPoint Client)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] MessageInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Message);
            NetClient.SendTo(MessageInBytes, Client);

            Console.WriteLine("Sending reply: " + Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your server code, what is "NetClient" ? You should send the reply using your `Server` variable, so the reply gets sent from the same port as the packet was received on, this will ensure the packet gets back to clients that are behind NAT.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot about that.
Socket NetClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
MySocket is the same.

But, if I send reply to the same port, must i change listening port on clinent? Or not?

Comment: Ok, as mentioned you should not use that to send the reply, use your existing `UdpClient Server = new UdpClient(Port);` to send the reply.

Comment: Still not working. I change this line: Server.Send(MessageInBytes, MessageInBytes.Length, Client); I think its problem with client because, before change this line and after, i have logs in console: Recieved from: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:abcde and message: Send reply to: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:abcde. So, i thing it send in right port, but my client not accept it? Meybe i must change listening port on client or something? But almost every message comes in other port.